# Combobox SelectedItem change all binded Textboxes in ListView that have the same bind value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have a ComboBox in a UserControl. This UserControl is shown when an item is selected from a ListView and is responsible for editing the values of the selected object. The problem is that if I have in the ListView more objects with the same value that the ComboBox is responsible to change, all of this values are change to the value of the selected item in the ListView.

I have this ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="AcorduriListView" ItemsSource="{Binding ., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AcordListViewItem}" />
```

With this template:

```
 <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="AcordListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Grid
                    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=DesignTimeData/AcordSampleData.xaml, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">


                   ...
                           <TextBlock x:Name="CategorieDescriptionTextBlock" Padding="3,0,0,0" Foreground="Black"
                                       Visibility="{Binding ElementName=CategorieTextBlock, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource StringNullOrEmptyToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                       Text="Completează categoria" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="CategorieTextBlock"
                                       Padding="3,0,0,0" Foreground="Black"
                                       Text="{Binding Categorie.Nume}"
                                       Visibility="{Binding ElementName=CategorieDescriptionTextBlock, Path=IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource InverteBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />

                           ...
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="rootPanel" Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="rootPanel" Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The ListView is bound to a collection of this Object:

```
 public class Acord : INotifyPropertyChanged, IChangeTracking
{
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   ...
   public int CategorieId { get; set; }

   public virtual Categorie Categorie { get; set; }
}
```

where `Categorie` is:

```
public class Categorie : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string Nume { get; set; }
   ....
    private ObservableCollection<Acord> _acorduri;

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Acord> Acorduri{ get; set; }        
}
```

When an item from this ListView is Selected, a UserControl is shown based on a trigger on the ListView SelectedIndex. The UserControl has it's DataContext bind to the ListView SelectedItem (an `Acord` object). From the many controls in this UserControl I have a Combobox `CategorieAcordComboBox` that has it's ItemsSource bind to a collection of `Categorie` objects.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,0,5,5" x:Name="CategorieAcordComboBox"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="Nume" SelectedValuePath="CategorieId"
                                          Text="{Binding Categorie.Nume}"

                                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" />
<DatePicker Grid.Row="3" Margin="5" FontSize="16" x:Name="DataAcorDatePicker"
                                            controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Data"
                                            SelectedDate="{Binding Data, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="4" x:Name="LocatieAcordTextBox" Margin="5"
                                         controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="True"
                                         controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Locație" FontSize="16"
                                         Text="{Binding Locatie, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

My problem is that when I select a diffrent item in ComboBox, while the Text binding is set to `Categorie.Nume` the content of all the TextBoxes `CategorieTextBlock` from the template that have the same value, changes to the selected value from ComboBox.

Video: http://screencast.com/t/bbRsb6RMwkZ7

Comment: In future, please start your question with a paragraph of text (instead of code), so that the beginning of your question can be seen properly in the various question lists on Stack Overflow (such as the Unanswered Questions list).

Comment: What _is_ `Categorie.Nume`? Without [a _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's not really possible to answer the question. If all the `TextBox` instances are bound e.g. to the same property, then of course they will all show the same value. You need to explain why it is you think they are being bound to different values. Please edit the post so that it includes a better code example and a clearer question.

Comment: I tried to explain it better. Hope it makes more sense. Thank you.